# Why the IK controller is not exist in the ThirdPersonController Animator component in the Inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: IK]

I'm trying to follow the instructions in the unity documents how to use Inverse Kinematics in this page:

[Inverse Kinematics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html)

But i don't have the IK Animator Controller when i select Controller for the Animator.

I tried adding the script now. But the hand the right hand is folded to the other side. It's not like it's holding the flash light: The script is attached to the ThirdPersonController. And i dragged to the script in the Inspector to the rightHandObj the EthanRightHand and to the lookObj i dragged the Flashlight.

But the hand seems to be wrong way.

[image: IK Control]

This is the script i'm using now the IKControl:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]

public class IKControl : MonoBehaviour
{

    protected Animator animator;

    public bool ikActive = false;
    public Transform rightHandObj = null;
    public Transform lookObj = null;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    //a callback for calculating IK
    void OnAnimatorIK()
    {
        if (animator)
        {

            //if the IK is active, set the position and rotation directly to the goal. 
            if (ikActive)
            {

                // Set the look target position, if one has been assigned
                if (lookObj != null)
                {
                    animator.SetLookAtWeight(1);
                    animator.SetLookAtPosition(lookObj.position);
                }

                // Set the right hand target position and rotation, if one has been assigned
                if (rightHandObj != null)
                {
                    animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, 1);
                    animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, 1);
                    animator.SetIKPosition(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rightHandObj.position);
                    animator.SetIKRotation(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, rightHandObj.rotation);
                }

            }

            //if the IK is not active, set the position and rotation of the hand and head back to the original position
            else
            {
                animator.SetIKPositionWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, 0);
                animator.SetIKRotationWeight(AvatarIKGoal.RightHand, 0);
                animator.SetLookAtWeight(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding the script to the `GameObject`?

Comment: @Hristo yes i tried now. But it's not working good yet, The hand is folded the wrong way it's not looks like it's holding the flashlight. I updated my question with what i did and the script i'm using.

Comment: And when you play is there any difference with the hand? Also did you change anything from the `Transform` of the hand?

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty game object to the flashlight and target that instead of the flashlight object itself. Hit play and then fiddle with the placement of the empty object until it is where you want it. Then just turn the flashlight into a prefab, stop play mode and make sure the flashlight in the scene matches the prefab (you can just use revert to do that if needed).

Now it would be doing exactly what you want every time. You could even have multiple prefabs with the empty object positioned differently to allow characters with larger or smaller hands to hold it convincingly.